# findViewById for textview returns null

Tags: android

Basically my question is quite common. However I have google and research all the possible solutions but to no avail thus asking on SO to resolve it.

My question is why when I findViewById for a textview, i got a null when returning back. Below is my activity and the XML file.

Activity:

```
public class Chicken extends ListActivity {

private TextView dishName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] chicken = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chicken_array);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
            chicken));

    dishName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    Log.w("test", "ok " + dishName); // returns null

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs" android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="185dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
    </FrameLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:background="@drawable/brown" android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/tabs">
        <TextView android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/order" android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="105dp" android:text="Send" android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></Button>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
            android:padding="3dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1" android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
            <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout01"
                    android:shrinkColumns="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1">
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow01">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                            android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="x1"></TextView>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:text="chicken"
                            android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow02">
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow03">
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow04">
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow05">
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow06">
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow07">
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow08">
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow09">
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow010">
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Hope somebody can help me out with this one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to create a gloabl reference to the textview as it is in the xml layout you specify for the tab activity. But you are trying to access the textview from its child activity(activity used to represent a tab.). When you use findViewById in the child activity it will look into the layout or view that was specified for the activity.

EDIT: Way to use app context.

Extend the application class and add a attribute of type textview. So in your activity you can access the application context  and set the text view a attribute.

```
MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
appContext.textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

In any other activity you can access that text view the same way.

```
MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();

This will have the textview appContext.textview
```

Comment: How do i create a global reference?

Comment: Sorry, but i am not very sure how to do this. In specific where do i write this? Is it to create a new class to extend Application? However, some of your terms are wrong when i try this.

Comment: Yes you need to extend the android.app.Application. its a singleton. So whenever you can getApplicationContext from the activity you are getting the same instance.

Comment: OKay. So what do i need to write in MyApplication activity? Is it like this?
`import android.app.Application;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

 public TextView textview;
}`

Comment: This is my code in Chicken activity.
`MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
 appContext.textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
 Log.w("test", "ok " + appContext.textview);`

However i still get null back.

Comment: Thank you for the solution you provided. I have already get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [setContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29) to tell the activity which layout to inflate and be set to.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); // Assuming your layout is called mylayout.xml

    String[] chicken = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chicken_array);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
            chicken));

    dishName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    Log.w("test", "ok " + dishName); // returns null

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Oh ya, I forget to mention that this activity is actually a part of my tab widget and i have already setContentView in my TabWiget activity. So do i need to set it here again?

Comment: You can try it. I guess you need it, otherwise how the the framework will know where to look up this view id? (I m not too familiar with TabActivity)

Comment: It cannot work. If i set the setContentView in this activity, the app crashes.